# how to get build number of other job in jenkins pipeine

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have created a pipeline where for build there is one job and for mail notification another job. I need to get the build job latest BUILD_NUMBER(either success or failure whatever) in mail notification job and i should publish the build job latest url as a mail notification regarding the buildstatus.
How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I think there are multiple ways that you could achieve this.  Let's call your 2 builds A (build) and B (mail notification).

1. Call B from A; pass whatever information you need in B as a parameter
2. You can use a combination of [this script](https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/cancel-builds-same-job.groovy#L11) and the [Job API](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Job.html).

For #2, I'm thinking you would have something like this in your B job:

```
def jobname = "<name of Job A>"
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobname)
def build = job.getLastBuild()
```